# wordpress wp_nav_menu not displaying in safari

Tags: css, wordpress, safari, cross-browser

Here is my css

```
#menubar{position:absolute; width:100%; height:42px; background:url(images/menubar-bg.jpg); margin-top:112px; }
    #menu-home{width:80%; height:42px; margin:0 auto;}
    #menu-home li{position:relative;}
    #menu-home>li>a{float:left; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family:arial; font-size:16px; font-weight:500;  padding:13px 2%; }
    #menu-home li.last-child{float:right; }
    #menu-home li.last-child a{padding:13px 0; color:#face30;}
    #menu-home .sub-menu{position:absolute; background:url(images/menu-hover-bg.jpg); width:100%; height:259px; top:0px; top:-220px; z-index:-1000;}
```

this works in all other browsers

here is my working url
[demo site](http://dnanetworks.com.preview.gearhost.com/)

Please Help.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your CSS and add float: left; to your **#menu-home li** element: `#menu-home li{ position:relative; float: left; }` . This way Safari will give LI's only the needed space.